# Linux - Send Ctrl+C using linux/bash commands for specific shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have written a shell script which processes a text input and displays the expected output, but post displaying the expected result - it waits for a `ctrl+c` in order for it to complete and for cursor to move to $_ space. How can I include this `ctrl+c` in my shell script itself ? or what is the shell script that does `ctrl+c` using bash/shell commands ?

The script is as follows:

`sed 's/\xC2\xA0//g' | awk '$1=="|"{if(f){print f" "$2;f=""}else{f=$2}}' filename.txt`

filename.txt contains:
https://justpaste.it/edit/30310895/df1838c844c0fcd1

Comment: Your script should just exit after the job is done. There must be something wrong with your script, you should post it here.

Comment: What does the script do after it has processed the input, and how does it process the input? Please post the script in your question.

Comment: @DavidDai updated the question

Comment: @dynamicJos what do you need sed for? It doesn't do anything at all here. Just remove `sed 's/\xC2\xA0//g' | ` from your script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pipeline that you show is essentially

```
sed expression | awk expression filename
```

This would run `awk` on the file `filename` while `sed` would sit around doing nothing while waiting for input from the user on its standard input (it would read what you typed on the terminal at that point).

To exit this script, you simply press <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> to signal the end of input to the `sed` process.  When `sed` notices that there will be nothing more to read, it terminates and the script exits (since that was what was "pausing" it).

Your current script is more or less equivalent of running

```
awk expression filename
sed expression
```

... since the two commands are not communicating with each other over the pipe.

What you want to be doing is

```
sed expression filename | awk expression
```

Here, `sed` is operating on the file and sends the result over to `awk` for further processing. `awk` is started without a filename, which means it reads from its standard input, which is connected to the standard output of `sed` via the pipe.

In your case, you want

```
sed 's/\xC2\xA0//g' filename.txt | awk '$1=="|"{if(f){print f" "$2;f=""}else{f=$2}}'
```

(If that pipeline does what you want it to do or not, I don't know, but now at least the `sed` and `awk` processes would be piped correctly).

Answer (score 3):

ctrl-c sends the "SIGINT" signal, so to send the same effect as ^C use

`kill -SIGINT` *pid-of-the-script*

Comment: how would I know pid of the shell that I am about to run ?

Comment: if you launch it using exec it will have the same PID as the process that used exec, else you have to wait until after it is launced to find the pid